# How to make the system display an image after RM on root?

Tags: boot, grub2, bootloader, rm

Is there possibly a way to cause the system to display an image (from another partition, so that the image isn't deleted upon `sudo rm -rf / --no-preserve-root`) when the operating system can't be found? I would assume that this, if possible, would be done through Grub, but I am unsure how to go about it. Basically, what I want to do is combine this with my other project, the "wipe HD on a predetermined failsafe code entered as login password" project. This is so that when `rm` is done on root, or in any other event that the system can't boot due to the fact that files couldn't be found on the HD, it displays an image with the custom dist logo and a "self destruct" icon, such as [this one](https://previews.123rf.com/images/alonastep/alonastep1512/alonastep151200247/49482737-Explosive-Hazard-Sign-Danger-symbol-Yellow-icon-isolated-in-black-triangle-on-white-background-Warni-Stock-Vector.jpg), with error information on the image. Is this in any way possible, though either Grub or through what may be left of the OS?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: grub files exist in /boot/grub usually; so they'll be gone  the only files available to you will be those in memory (ie. open & thus inode delete pending)

Comment: Hmmm... Is there possibly a way to exclude /boot/grub from the `rm` (even if it means in the command itself, since I'll be putting it into an automated script)?

Comment: i'm not familiar (and don't see help in `man rm`) with any exclude for `rm`, but given you're doing this in a script; I'd walk the `/` directory deleting as you go** (skipping `rm`) leaving the image/files you want to use to last; displaying your image then deleting it & of course last /bin/rm

Comment: I'm sure I could also have a 512MB or so partition that could store files for the image and so on, then tell Grub if possible to refer to that rather than the install partition(s)

Comment: if your 512mb partition is mounted; it'll get wiped with the rest.  to protect from wipe you can have it umounted, but then you'll have to not-delete the `mount` command to allow yourself to use it (along with `rm` to later..)

Comment: @guiverc would there be a way to have the partition outside the installation? or, could I have some sort of grub script embedded within grub that would be executed on boot failure?

Comment: grub (stages 1.5-2) are inside the /boot partition; but any script running will be in memory (inode busy so its not deleted but pending delete;  however file entry will be deleted, so any later access will not find it).  back to grub, and stage 1 is outside of  the partition yes - but that's just the 512byte boot sector which isn't much space (and do you want to use that!).  any partition outside of installation is unmounted going back prior comment...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68946/discussion-between-brenden-mcfarling-and-guiverc).